# Find the volume of the piece of the region between the planes $x+y+z = 1$ and $2x + 2y + z = 2$ which lies in the first octant.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume of the piece of the region between the planes $x+y+z = 1$
and $2x + 2y + z = 2$ which lies in the first octant.
I got:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{1-y-x}^{2-2y-2x} \;dz \;dy\;dx $$

Am I correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me